# Convert Datetime format in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I need to convert the Long value to a date time format.

Eg., Long value - 20080506015600658
datetime format - Tue May 06 01:56:00 IST 2008

Comment: There's no built in simple conversion from one to the other. There are some ugly string manipulation hacks or lots of fun with maths. Where is this value coming from, and is there no possibility for it to be changed before it gets to SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the ugly way to do it via string manipulation:

```
declare @start bigint
set @start = 20080506015600658

select CONVERT(datetime,
    STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(
        t,15,0,'.'),
          13,0,':'),
          11,0,':'),
           9,0,'T'),
           7,0,'-'),
           5,0,'-'))
from (select CONVERT(varchar(20),@start) as t) n
```

Which basically forces it to conform to the pattern `YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss.mil` before doing the conversion.

---

And here's the ugly as sin way to do it with maths:

```
declare @start bigint
set @start = 20080506015600658

select
    DATEADD(year,  (@start/10000000000000) - 1, --Because we already have 1 on starting date
    DATEADD(month, (@start/100000000000)%100 - 1, --Because we already have 1 on starting date
    DATEADD(day,   (@start/1000000000)%100 - 1, --Because we already have 1 on starting date
    DATEADD(hour,  (@start/10000000)%100,
    DATEADD(minute,(@start/100000)%100,
    DATEADD(second,(@start/1000)%100,
    DATEADD(millisecond,@start%1000,CONVERT(datetime2,'0001-01-01'))))))))
```